# Send SMS Not Functioning after Encrypted

Tags: java, android, function, encryption

This function will call another function (prince.Encrypt) that encrypts (PRINCE algorithm) the text message. But once it is linked with the encryption function, sending SMS fails. The function was working fine before encryption was included.

```
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
             public void onClick(View v, String args) 
                  {             
                       String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                       String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();              
                       if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
                       {
                            LongBuffer messageBuf = TooLong.messageToLongBuffer(message); 
                            messageBuf.flip();
                            long[] messageData = new long[messageBuf.remaining()];
                            LongBuffer i = messageBuf.get(messageData);
                            String v1=prince.Encrypt(i, k0, kop, k1, t);
                            sendSMS(phoneNo, v1);
                        }               
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please enter both phone number and message.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)
                  {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  }
         });        
    }
 //---sends a SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String v1)
    {      
     /*
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, test.class), 0);                
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
        */

     String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
     String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    switch (getResultCode())
    {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
    }
   }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    switch (getResultCode())
    {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;         
    }
   }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

       SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
       sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, v1, sentPI, deliveredPI);               
    }    

}
```

Comment: Is it over 160 characters? In that case you need to split it

Comment: @LittleChild no, i just used a short text which is "test".

Comment: An example would be great. What the before and after texts look like.

Comment: @LittleChild the plain text could be anything that could be typed in phone but for testing matter, i am using "0". The encrypted text should be "D9B4BDBB44C7E08B".